# Trajectory of a falling body

Tags: orbital-motion

Let us assume a small body falling into sun. It has zero initial velocity. So I want to know, taking what type of path will the body move towards sun. There maybe two cases, falling from a greater height or falling from smaller height.

**In both the cases will the body have same path?**

**Will the body travel in straight line towards the centre of sun or in curved elliptical path towards the centre of sun?**

Answer (score 2):

If the object has no tangential velocity relative to the sun, it will fall in a straight line regardless of its height. Otherwise would mean there would be acceleration coming from nowhere, which is a problem.